# Unknown type name 'NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN'

Tags: iphone, xcode

I got this error while integrating a framework from an existing project to my project.

Error : Unknown type name 'NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN'

How could I fix this ?

Answer (score 7):

I found the issue behind this issue.

The issue Unknown type name 'NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN' arise due to the missing of Foundation framework. And I found the Foundation framework is added in the -Prefix.pch file. I forgot to add the "Prefix Header" path in the framework after I moved it to my project.

So after setting the Prefix.pch file's path, the errors gone.