# Xcode 11.1 could not build module 'foundation' for Device only

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, foundation, xcode11.1

Project build and run successfully on the simulator but failed on a real device.

**Config:** 
macOS: 10.15 beta, iOS 13.1, Xcode 11.1

AppDelegate imports:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <Photos/Photos.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
```

The project contains both Objective-C and Swift Framework and files.

Even after Restarting Mac/Xcode, clean build folder, Derived Data and use 'Legacy Build System'

It was working until yesterday night :(

Getting error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: plz give more information about iOS version device and some import line in your AppDelegate file, seem your project using Objective-C language?

Comment: @TraiNguyen please see updated question

Comment: My suggestion is to update your Xcode with `11.2.1` version

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia can't custom Swift framework build on same version

Comment: @HarshalWani try `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`

Comment: @TraiNguyen already present in AppDelegate.m, even moved to .h same issue

Comment: @HarshalWani try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54999190/3146021)

Comment: Trai, in proj not using pch file

Comment: @HarshalWani are you checking Foundation framework be added into your project? Try remove and add all your using framework again.